# under which extension does photorec search for .tex file

Tags: latex, photorec

under which extension  does photorec search for .tex file?

I cannot run the command fidentity using terminal.

So does anybody know of that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Photorec just sees that as a normal text file, IIRC. Same for any other script or source code.

Answer (score 1):

Photorec comes with a lot of pre-defined file extensions by default. [Amongst many](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec) TEX files having the extension `.tex` are already included.

To find out if a given file type will be recognized we can run the following command on a sample file we had created for this purpose:

```
fidentify sample.myextension
```

Only if there was no existing file signature we will get the result `unknown`. In all other cases we may had used a custom extension for a known file type. These will be recovered but may get another extension after recovery.

It is also possible to add a [custom file signature](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Add_your_own_extension_to_PhotoRec) to including these files for recovery.

Answer (score 0):

`photorec` is a software for data recovery, it reads what's left of a broken medium and tries to scrap data using [libmagic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libmagic1) to find data.

There's no program called `fidentity` that I'm aware of.